# Is LDAP included in MFP CLI?

Tags: ldap, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a little question w.r.t MFP Client

Does Mobilefirst Client (ie MFP CLI) has built-in LDAP configuration (or)  if not can LDAP be included by any means ?

Answer (score 0):

LDAP is a protocol: http://www.gracion.com/server/whatldap.html

It is not related to the CLI, which is just a bunch of command-line commands to make operations that are specific to MFP. LDAP is not specific to MFP.

You can integrate with LDAP. Read more here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/search/ldap?scope=SSHS8R_7.1.0

Comment: We installed "Security (or) Tivoli Directory Server" and configured LDAP and added user entries via LDIF files.  Through MFP CLI we built a project which includes LDAPLoginModule but getting error message "Invalid credentials".  There are many URL's for Open LDAP but could not find a good URL for TDS.  Any help is highly appreciated